# Cascade Dropdown in Angular Reactive Form

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-reactive-forms, cascadingdropdown

For the cascading dropdown, On changing the country, the state value must be reset. 
How can i achieve that ? 
This is what i did 
[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cascading-dropdown-angular-we2hx6)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I leave you [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cascading-dropdown-angular-wkuskk?file=app/app.component.ts) your fork working as you need.

All you have todo do is subscribe to the changes of the 'Country' field with **valueChanges**, something like what I do here with the *formFieldCountryValueChanges$* Observable:

```
private formFieldCountryValueChanges$: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      Country: ['', [Validators.required]],
      State: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });

    this.countries = this.selectService.getCountries();

    this.formFieldCountryValueChanges$ = this.myForm
      .get('Country')
      .valueChanges.pipe(
        tap((_arrayStates) => {
          this.myForm.patchValue({ State: '' });
          return _arrayStates;
        })
      );
    this.formFieldCountryValueChanges$.subscribe();
  }
```